# why send_keys can't work after right click in chrome and ie, but firefox is fine?

Tags: windows, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

i want to copy a image in the page with right click and alt+y,and follow code is work well in the firefox,but chrome and ie. so i can't get the image from the clipboard.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto('www.baidu.com')
b.img(:src=>"http://www.baidu.com/img/baidu_sylogo1.gif").right_click
b.send_keys ("{alt}y")
```

and follow code can work well

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto('www.baidu.com')
b.send_keys :tab
```

this can work well

Comment: There is a save feature for images that is not implemented yet.

Comment: You realize that keyboard shortcuts and right click menus are browser specific, and do not follow any kind of standard such as HTML etc..

Comment: please god tell me you are not trying to bypass a captcha..  there are better ways around those than meatbots.  the only people that need to use meatbots to solve captchas are spammers and thieves, and we have very low tolerance for those types of folks round these parts..

Comment: no no no!! I am not a spammer or thief, the application is a wap application, I use the wair-webdriver and watir-user-agent to test it, and there is a captcha in login before submit the form, so I have to get it from the image. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you do `b.send_keys ("{alt}y")`, you are just typing the letters {, a, l, etc.

Try this instead:

```
b.send_keys([:alt, 'y'])
```

Watir and Watir-Webdriver use different inputs for send_keys - see [here](http://watirmelon.com/2011/07/19/sending-special-keys-to-watir-webdriver/).

Note: I did not test your full script with this. To be honest, I cannot figure out how to manually copy the image to clipboard using alt+y.

Comment: when you right click on a image of chrome,in the right menu, y is the shortcut to copy image. It is work well in firefox,but not in ie and chrome. as I know watir-webdriver not implement image.save(path) function so I need copy it to clipboard and then write it to my computer.

Comment: and i also test the send_keys after right click on image
test1
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
b.goto('www.baidu.com')
b.img(:src=>"http://www.baidu.com/img/baidu_sylogo1.gif").right_click
b.send_keys :arrow_right
b.send_keys([:alt, 'y'])
test2
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto('www.baidu.com')
b.img(:src=>"http://www.baidu.com/img/baidu_sylogo1.gif").right_click
b.send_keys :arrow_right
b.send_keys([:alt, 'y'])
and in test1 you can see the righ menu is highlight in blue but the test 2 is not

Comment: @Justin,  on a windows box, if you ALT-Rightclick  you will see the shortcuts underlined (in chrome anyway)

Comment: @Chuck, thanks. I see it now in Chrome, though having ALT pressed just temporarily displays the menu. Oddly, I am finding that Firefox only has the Copy Image option for some images. The sample site in the question, being one that doesn't have it. I agree with Doug's point that the solution is bound to be browser specific.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know why you want to save the image.  Would a screen shot work?  If it will, try this:

```
b.driver.save_screenshot "#{Time.now.to_i}.png"
```

Comment: I want to copy the image to the clipboard,then save it to my computer. Because I want to  get a Verification code from the picture by a dll tool. But Watir-webdriver is not implement the image.save function. so I need copy it to clipboard and then write it to my computer then use it.

Comment: and this is my code
while(@browser.text_field(:name=>"validateCode").exists?)
      @browser.img(:id=>"validateCodeImg").right_click
      @browser.send_keys("{alt}y")
#      @browser.send_keys("Y")
  
      File.open('vcode.png', 'wb'){ |fh|
        fh.write Win32::Clipboard.data(Clipboard::DIB)
      }
      vcode_class = VCode.new
      png_path = File.expand_path("vcode.png")
      code = vcode_class.get_vcode_by_file(png_path)

Comment: It looks like your issue may be simply that the Save picture shortcut is browser specific.  You'll need to construct a case statement based on your current browser.  Firefox uses 'V' and IE uses 'S'.  You should be able to send just the key without an Alt, but you may need to try it both ways.

Comment: thank you, firefox use the 'Y' and Ie use 'c', Chrome is 'Y' the same as firefox. Is there have other way to the Specified picture in the web page use ruby.

Comment: Ah, I guess you're using those browsers in another language?  You could attempt to  get the path and download the file directly, but I don't know what code you would use to do this.

Comment: Honestly the best way may be to get the value from the server itself.  Just pass it into your test externally and forget about what the image looks like.  There are some things that are not worth the time to automate.  A manual test can verify that the values are showing up correctly, and you can bypass it for your automated tests that need to hit that page.

Answer (score 1):

Do not waste any time trying to automate validation such as a Captcha *(Completely Automated Public Turing Test To Tell Computers and Humans Apart)* or other authentication system designed to thwart automation.  Yes it can be done but it is effectively engaging in an arms race or tilting at windmills.  More importantly it brings no value to your employer.

The right way to automate around a captcha or verification code is to configure the test environment such that the code is predictable.  Many captcha tools, or verification tools, have the ability to operate in 'test' mode where they have a set response.  You'd never configure a production environment that way, but you can easily (and ought to) configure a test environment that way.

Talk to the folks who setup and control the test environment.  They just need some logic that knows it's a test env and then uses the proper api call for the captcha or authorization tool (like the google authorizer, or the widgets that spit out numbers every 5 minutes)  to put it in test mode so it uses a predictable validation response.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:  http://captcha.biz/doc/aspnet/api/captcha-configuration-reference.html#BotDetect.Configuration.ITestModeConfiguration

If you are using something that does not support this, then you can either configure the system to skip the captcha entirely, OR you can configure it to point some test stub that you create (instead of the real captcha system).  This will be a small bit of code that you or your developers create that uses the same api as a real captcha, but always expects the same answer.  In that case everything behaves exactly like it was talking to a real captcha service, but the little stub code it is talking to always sends the same image with the same 'answer' e.g. 'testing'

This sort of thing is normal for test environments, where all sorts of third party stuff is either disabled, or put into a test mode, or connected to a test sandbox (e.g. captcha's, advertising, website analytics, tracking pixels, credit card authorization services, etc)

Comment: I reproduced the error. The site looks like company logo, not a chaptcha.

Comment: Of course I‘m a autoteser, because this web appliaction have a verification code when login. so I need to get it before sumbit.

Comment: Yes the image of the web site in the example is a company logo, but it is not matter, I just want to copy the image to the clipboard , the web application which i want to test is a wap application, and it is need to user watir-user-agent to test. In order to simplify I use the website to test copy image.

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of the previous comments, its sounds like you ultimately just need a way to save the image. I assume copying it to clipboard is not actually important.

So you do all your navigation in Watir-Webdriver and then switch to one of the other Ruby gems (ex Open-URI or Net-Http) to download the image.

The following is an example using Open-URI:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require "open-uri"

save_file = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Setup\Desktop\image.png'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto('www.baidu.com')
image_location = b.img.src

File.open(save_file, 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write open(image_location).read
end
```